AWS IAM policy to prevent creation of any resource without a specific suffix
I nned an AWS IAM policy to prevent the creation of any resource whose name doesn't comply with my company naming convention.
All resources names must end with -mySuffix.
Basically, I need something like this:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "*:Create*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "*:ResourceArn": "*-mySuffix"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Unfortunately, this doesn't work... yet.
I tried with one JSON paragraph section per resource type (S3, SQS, Dynamodb, and so on), but it doesn't work very reliably.

One cannot start the IAM Policy Condition with * (wildcard or asterisk) character. One can't have the key, in your case <any service>:ResourceArn as *:ResourceArn. You'd have to specify all services ... Then, instead of *-suffix, use it as prefix-* and then you can have the rule.
That's how AWS works.
You can't use it in AWS Config either, to query for IAM Policy or Role. You need to start with a prefix before using special characters *. I think it applies to ? as well.

Thanks for this comment. The pseudocode provided in the question was simply an illustration of the desired policy, not an actual working one, of course.

Also, I need to prevent anyone with the policy from creating a resource (any resource, a specrtum as large as possible, IAM, EC2, S3, Dynamo...) that doesn'nt have a specific suffix in it's name, like mybucketS3-suffix
